# Managing a long PHP request

Tags: php, angularjs

So I have a PHP file that basically calls an API and fetches a lot of data about a `user_id`. This whole request takes a few minutes to fully complete on average. So far I've been having a PHP file that does this and I query it with AngularJS like a basic `POST` request so:

`mineData.php`

```
while data not complete {
    getData();
}
http_response_code(200); //Send success
```

`userController.js`

```
$scope.mineData(); //Send a POST request to the PHP file
```

However, for some reason I am getting a "success" signal almost immediately which leads me to believe that the PHP process isn't even running, and indeed it doesn't seem to be after checking my database. How can I manage long PHP jobs like this and give updates on its progress to the user?

Edit: It seems like sometimes it does succeed, but I think there is a better way to delegate this task. What are the best practices and how can I  do it? (something akin to a cron job?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give you exaclty what you want when we cant see what this mineData.php is doing. However, you probably want to split things up:
mineData.php does all the heavy lifting, no interaction with the user
isMineDataReady.php could be a small script setup to check if mineData.php has completed.

Aditionally, if your script is holding up the user, you can move it to command line and run it with exec, make sure you put > /dev/null 2>&1 & on the end of the command to make php continue even though the exec call has not completed